# Remember unauthenticated action

Tags: angular

Is there a way built into angular2 similar to Django's 'next action' that remembers what a user was trying to do when they attempt to perform an authenticated action?

Scenario:

1. User is not logged in
2. User attempt to see user X's profile
3. User is redirected to login page
4. User logs in
5. User is redirected to user X's profile page

Comment: Are you using a guard for the redirection process?

Comment: Yes I am using a system similar to the authguard / authservice style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Angular2 guard you could do the following:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  // Logged in logic.

  // If not logged in store the state.url
  localStorage.setItem('redirectUrl', state.url);

  // Not logged in logic.
}
```

In your login function once a successful login you can then redirect using:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('redirectUrl')) {
  this.router.navigate([localStorage.getItem('redirectUrl')]);
}
```